# How to display std::string as a string instead of an array inside Visual Studio Watch Window

Tags: string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, std

When I take the variable 
        std::string jjj("bobby");

and stick it in the watch window, I get

```
-       jjj {...}   std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
+       [actual members]    {...}   std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >
        [0] 98 'b'  char
        [1] 111 'o' char
        [2] 98 'b'  char
        [3] 98 'b'  char
        [4] 121 'y' char
```

Is there any way to get it to show up in the watch window as "bobby"?

EDIT:

It turns out that this is only happening for projects that have the /clr flag set.  The strings show up properly in unmanaged projects.

Comment: It turns out that it is working correctly for other projects on my system.

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 should have this functionality by default. Something must be messed up with your installation. [Here is a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx) to a blog post on creating your own debug visualizers. It references where the install paths are for the files that handle this feature. Try checking that your computer has the all the files.

Comment: Upon further investigation, the debugger watch window is working correctly for my other projects, so it isn't a general VS configuration issue.